# Proxy not allowing communication between reactjs and nodeJS application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I am working on a reactjs application with a nodeJS backend hooked up to my MS SQL Database.
The problem is I am having trouble getting my data to be saved because the app is running on port 3000 and node is on 3001.

I have read about this and been instructed to add   `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001",` to the`package.json` file, reset the server, clear the cache, delete the node_module folder and run `npm install` again and I assure you nothing has worked so far.

In my `server.js` file, line 23 which reads `` console.log(`Incoming request to /api/saveDriverInformation: ${req.method} ${req.url}`); `` does get hit and this is logged in my cmd prompt. However the post in the `saveDriverInformationController.js` doesn't get hit.

Instead I get the following error `xhr.js:256     POST http://localhost:3000/api/saveDriverInformation 404 (Not Found)` which Is leading me to believe the proxy is not working.

Appreciate if I could get some assistance regarding this, I have posted what I believe to be the relevant code below.

This is my package.json file

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "reactrefreshed",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
/* rest of code here */
```

Code of my profile.tsx page (or my form where I hit the submit button

`profile.tsx`

```
onSubmit: async (values) => {
  try { 
    const response = await axios.post("/api/saveDriverInformation", values); 
    if (response.status === 200) { 
      console.log("Data saved successfully");
    } else { 
      console.error("Error while saving data:", response.data);
    }
  } catch (error) {
```

saveDriverInformationController.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const db = require('./db_connect');  

const router = express.Router(); 
router.use(bodyParser.json());
console.log("Entered");
// Route to save driver information
router.post('/api/saveDriverInformation', async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Here");
  try {
    const driverData = req.body;

    console.log('Received a POST request to save driver information'); 
 
    const pool = await db.connectToDB();
    console.log('Connected to the database'); 
 
    const sqlQuery = `
      INSERT INTO DriverInformation (DriverID, FirstName, LastName )
      VALUES (
        @DriverID, @FirstName, @LastName 
      );
    `;

    // Define the parameters to be used in the query
    const parameters = {
      DriverID: driverData.DriverID,
      FirstName: driverData.FirstName,
      LastName: driverData.LastName,
 
    };

    // Execute the SQL query
    await pool
      .request()
      .input('DriverID', parameters.DriverID)
      .input('FirstName', parameters.FirstName)
      .input('LastName', parameters.LastName)
      .query(sqlQuery);
    console.log('Driver information saved successfully');  
 
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Driver information saved successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error saving driver information:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while saving driver information' });
  } finally {
    
    await db.closeDB();
    console.log('Database connection closed');  
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");  
const saveDriverInformationController = require("./saveDriverInformationController");

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
 
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",  
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));
 
app.use("/api/saveDriverInformation", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`Incoming request to /api/saveDriverInformation: ${req.method} ${req.url}`);
  next();  
});

 
app.use("/api/saveDriverInformation", saveDriverInformationController);
 
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set up your router like:

```js
app.use("/api/saveDriverInformation", saveDriverInformationController);
```

The routes you define *inside* the router will be relative to `api/saveDriverInformation`, so:

```js
router.post('/api/saveDriverInformation', async (req, res) => { ... });
```

will be available at `/api/saveDriverInformation/api/saveDriverInformation`.

Solution:

```js
// in app
app.use("/api", saveDriverInformationController);

// in router
router.post('/saveDriverInformation', async (req, res) => { ... });
```